# NDK tools unable to decrypt New BBID Tokens

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-10

Hello BlackBerry developers.
since the BlackBerry ID site was updated I have noticed that the NDK tools are unable to decrypt the new bbidtoken.csk files. The Momentics IDE's signing wizard also cannot connect to the site. As such, it is not possible to use a new csk to acquire debug tokens or sign apps.

I am still able to use my old bbidtoken created before the update. The signing servers themselves are still operational, so using the command-line blackberry-signer/debugtokenrequest tools works normally. However, when I attempt to use the new bbidtoken.csk, I get the message: "Error: The specified CSK password is not valid."

I believe the issue is being caused by an update to the BlackBerry encryption algorithms/standards used to create the new tokens. If so, would it be possible to provide an updated bundle of the signing *.jar packages?

Thank you for your continued support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There hasn't been any changes made to this system. The error you're seeing is usually caused by your new BlackBerry ID Token (bbidtoken.csk) and existing Developer Certificate no longer having the same password.  BlackBerry Momentics expects them to be the same.

To fix you could use the same password for a new BlackBerry ID Token or create a new BlackBerry Developer Certificate with a matching password.  You can do so in Momentics by going to Window menu, Preferences, BlackBerry, Signing.  On this screen you'll see a button to create a new Developer Certificate.  Changing the Developer Certificate will not affect the upgradability of your apps.

Comment: Thank you for the instant response! I installed Momentics into Windows and successfully obtained a token using the IDE which now works inside Linux.

I must have done something to break my installation or system libraries, because re-installing on Linux hasn't worked before. It might have to do with the libwebkitgtk-1 that I have to obtain manually... or the tinkering I have been doing to enable building using newer gcc...

Thank you for continuing to maintain the BlackBerry 10 infrastructure.

Comment: Happy to help out.  :)  Glad to hear you are up and running again.